# Can I force current hosts group to be identified as another in a playbook include?

Tags: ansible

The current case is this:
I have a playbook which provisions a bunch of servers and installs apps to these servers.
One of these apps already has it's own ansible playbook which I wanted to use. Now my problem arises from this playbook, as it's limited to `hosts: [prod]` and the host groups I have in the upper-level playbook are different.

I know I could just use `add_host` to add the needed hosts to a `prod` group, but that is a solution which I don't like.

So my question is: Is there a way to add the current hosts to a new host group in the include statement?
Something like `- include: foo.yml prod={{ ansible_host_group }}`

Or can I somehow include only the tasks from a playbook?

Comment: Playbook may contain multiple Plays with different hosts each, so there is no way to overwrite `hosts` attribute while including a Playbook. And your example wouldn't work just because `ansible_host_group` is not defined here – you may include either Playbook (where hosts are not defined yet) or Tasks (where hosts are already fixed). Consider using `[prod:children]` entry in your inventory containing your actual group names, or call `group_by: key=prod` task for hosts before including foo.yml playbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no direct way to do this.

> Now my problem arises from this playbook, as it's limited to
>   `hosts: [prod]`

You can setup host's more flexible via extra vars:

```
- name: add role fail2ban
  hosts: '{{ target }}'
  remote_user: root
  roles:
    - fail2ban
```

Run it:

```
ansible-playbook testplaybook.yml --extra-vars "target=10.0.190.123"
ansible-playbook testplaybook.yml --extra-vars "target=webservers"
```

Is this workaround suitable for you?

Comment: Too bad this isn't a real option, since I can't go and modify the playbook

Comment: I'll accept this, as it's the right way to do it, but it doesn't address my problem :)